# Python3 UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-requests

I wrote the following code in python3 which runs perfect:

```
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
message = ""
run_again = False

try:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, allow_redirects=False)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    message = "Connection Failed!"
    run_again = True

if "משתמש לא מזוהה" in response.text:
    message = "User Was Logged Out Automatically!"
```

But when I cut the internet, I get the following error:

```
    if "משתמש לא מזוהה" in response.text:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment
```

how can I solve this?

Comment: Well, yes. What should `response` be equal to if there wasn't a response? Why/how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the internet, an exception will be raised on this line.

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, allow_redirects=False)
```

That would make `response` undefined.
One way to resolve this is to move the `if` statement to the `try` block

```
try:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, allow_redirects=False)
    if "משתמש לא מזוהה" in response.text:
       message = "User Was Logged Out Automatically!"
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    message = "Connection Failed!"
    run_again = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the response variable outside the try/except code.

Answer (score 0):

If `requests.get()` raises an exception, then you can't use `response` since it won't be assigned.

You can instead define a function, e.g. `handle_response` and call that function within the `try` block.

```
def handle_response(response):
   if "משתמש לא מזוהה" in response.text:
        message = "User Was Logged Out Automatically!"

now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
message = ""
run_again = False

try:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, allow_redirects=False)
    handle_response(response)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    message = "Connection Failed!"
    run_again = True
```

The `handle_response` function will only be called if the `requests.get()` does not raise any exceptions.